# Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug

Tags: java, android, react-native, path, android-emulator

After resetting my computer and installing from react-native document, I started getting gradle error. I set the paths ANDROID_HOME part I downloaded the packages from android studio but I still get this problem. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQl7E.png)

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Masa�st�\gradle\slow\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Debugger attached.Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\gradle\slow\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.15.0

BU�LD FAILED in 2s

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Masaüstü\gradle\slow\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Masaüstü\gradle\slow\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Masa�st�\gradle\slow\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Debugger attached.Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\gradle\slow\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.15.0

BU�LD FAILED in 2s

```
at makeError (C:\Masaüstü\gradle\slow\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Masaüstü\gradle\slow\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Masaüstü\gradle\slow\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Masaüstü\gradle\slow\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I tried to read all the documentation many times and make it from scratch. but it didn't work.

Comment: try cleaning gradle

Comment: windows:-
cd android
gradlew clean
npm start --reset-cache
npm run android

Comment: Linux:-
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..

Comment: i tried gradlew clean but it gives me build failed error

Comment: I figured out. It's because onedrive. Made my desktop location more than one. When i change the build location on the documents. It is done!